# Java integration on Phonegap Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

In my Phonegap Blackberry application, there is a need to integrate Java. My requirement is, after the splash or loading screen, I need to have an alert dialog with two buttons(options) say YES or NO.  When I click on YES one HTML page should be loaded and on clicking NO, should load another HTML page. This is the flow to be done in Java and please guide me to do the same.
Thanks and regards
Ashwini

Comment: Why don't you do this in javascript? PhoneGap is not java-based platform. It uses HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily done with javascript.

jQuery Version:

```
var r=confirm("Yes or No?");
if (r==true)
  {
  $('body').load('page1.html');
  }
else
  {
  $('body').load('page2.html');
  }
```

Javascript Only Version:

```
var r=confirm("Yes or No?");
if (r==true)
  {
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'page1.html', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
            document.innerHTML= this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send();
  }
else
  {
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'page2.html', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
            document.innerHTML= this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send();
  }
```